# Linux Password Dictionary

Tags: linux

In Linux, When we try to set a user password the system always checks if it is a dictionary word, I want to know Where is this dictionary located in a Linux machine.??

Is it possible to configure the Linux system not to check the dictionary when we set a user password.??

Comment: Maybe [`/usr/share/dict/words`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_%28Unix%29) or something?

Comment: It might be helpful to note your flavour of linux (Ubuntu, CentOS, etc...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the files in `/etc/pam.d` you'll see lines like:

```
  password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
```

This controls the checking. Documentation of [pam_cracklib](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_cracklib) is available. It uses libcrack2, which is also [documented](http://linux.die.net/man/8/create-cracklib-dict).

Comment: I don't think pam_cracklib is part of standard install on say Ubuntu. Did you set this up for your machine? or, what is your unix flavor? ([Force strong passwords in CentOS Linux](http://www.syn-ack.org/centos-linux/force-strong-passwords-in-centos/))

Comment: This is standard on Fedora and RedHat.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question: In a recent CentOS installation, I found the dictionary in `/usr/share/cracklib/pw_dict.pwd`. I was able to see the (pass)words with the `strings` command.

Answer (score -1):

In red hat linux 9 the path for the dictionary words is /usr/share/dict/linux.words

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).